# internet connection problem in virtualbox

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I have installed Windows 7 in virtualbox. But I cant access internet.
Can You please tell me the way how can I connect to internet in virtualbox. Internet is running smoothly in my host Ubuntu..

Comment: I had something similar a while ago. Are you able to use the internet when you don't specify a URL but use an IP address instead? I.e. what happens when you go to http://74.125.224.72/?

Answer (score 2):

In the window showing the guest, right-click on the network icon (two computer monitors) and click Network Adapters. Select Attached to Bridged Adapter and make sure that "Cable connected" is checked. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should download and install the latest version of Virtualbox from this site www.virtualbox.org, and then check this 2 tutorials:1)http://christophermaier.name/blog/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox
2)http://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2012/02/28/configuring-virtualbox-guests-to-access-the-internet-and-be-accessible-from-the-host/